# How make class with overriding methods in Android?

Tags: android, overriding

I'm new in Android, how can I do that?
I created a class `FixedDelayTimer` where I use `TimerTask`.

```
public class FixedDelayTimer extends Timer{

public FixedDelayTimer()
{
...
}

public void start(long delay, long period)
{
    ...
    updateTask = new TimerTask() {
        // !! method run() should be override
        public void run() {
            // TODO
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

}

I would like method `run()` from `TimerTask` to be override like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
FixedDelayTimer updateTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(com.example.eleizo.firstapplication.R.layout.activity_main); 

    updateTask = new FixedDelayTimer(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            new DownloadImage().execute("http://");
        }
    };       
}
```

EDIT AFTER RIGHT ANSWER:

```
// !! method task() should be override
public void task(){
    // TODO
}

//таймер запущен, задача выполняется
public void start(long delay, long period)
{
    ...
    updateTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            task();
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

Comment: Which error r u facing?

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: When I try override run() method in onCreate() there is error: "Method does not override method from its superclass"

Comment: then it means that there is nothing to override. Your `FixedDelayTimer ` doesn't have `run` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, because run is a part of an anonymous inner class. In this method:

```
public void start(long delay, long period)
{
    ...
    updateTask = new TimerTask() {
        // !! method run() should be override
        public void run() {
            // TODO
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

You cannot override `run` because it isn't a part of your class. It is a part of an inner class you create there. You actually need to declare `run` **in your class** if you want to override it. And by declare in the class, I don't mean in a nested class. I mean inside your class

Comment: Yes... sorry, stupid mistake. I edit my question. Thanks a lot.